# Creating a Java Interface with methods that accept any class as a parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, generics

I am creating an application  in JSF and using hibernate. For every JSF page I want to perform CRUD operations. To Simplify my coding, I want to create an interface that has the four methods to perform CRUD.
I want the methods in the interface to accept any class as a parameter.

Here is my sample code:

```
interface performCrud
{
    public void Create(Class cl);
    public void delete(Class cl);
    public void update(Class cl);
    public void read(Class cl);
}

class newuser implements performCrud
{

    @override
    public void Create(UserDao userdao)
    {

    }

    //Other implementations Follows

}

class newproduct implements performCrud
{

   @override
   public void Create(productDao productdao)
   {

   }

   // Other implementations Follows

}
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: okay, the edit made it a bit clearer. Have a look at Java Generics, they might help you. Make the interface use a generic type, then the implementations can specify it

Comment: Why? Hibernate already has the `Session` class that does exactly this.

Comment: Spring Data will do this (and more) for you. http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

Comment: How Can I implements this in Hibernate@mabi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, you should use generics :

```
interface performCrud<T>
{
    public void Create(T cl);
    public void delete(T cl);
    public void update(T cl);
    public T read();
}

class newuser implements performCrud<UserDao>{

    @override
    public void Create(UserDao userdao)
    {

    }
    ....
}
```

Oh, and BTW, your `read` method should probably return `T` instead of accepting an argument of type `T`. I changed the interface accordingly.

Comment: How Can I make read to Return T instead of accepting parameter

Comment: @MorganM See my change in the interface

Comment: then there is something else I got stuck in jsf. ok I have a datatable that populate data from a curtain table at the last column I have added edit button. So I want when the user click the edit button populate row value to a <p:dialogbox>. How Can I achieve this. I will Realy appreciate.

Comment: @MorganM I don't know. I suggest you post a new question, since it doesn't seem related to this question.